# combining PHP functions

Tags: php

I've inherited some php that parses an xml file to populate a page full of unordered lists and am wondering if there is a way to consolidate the php functions to make them more efficient.

There are 25 or so functions like the following:

```
function oaAccounting(){

  // load SimpleXML
  $term = new SimpleXMLElement('training_list.xml', null, true);
  echo <<<EOF
  <ul>
EOF;

  foreach($term as $term)
  {
     if(preg_match("/accounting/i", $term->keyword)){
        echo <<<EOF
        <li>{$term->name}</li>
EOF;
     }
  }
  echo '</ul>';
}
```

each one scans the xml file for the term/keyword it's searching for and adds the term as a list element to an unordered list specific to that function. The next function does the same thing but for a different term/keyword and adds it to a separate unordered list.

is there a way to combine all this to prevent having to do the foreach and if 25 times in a row?

Thanks!

Comment: Rewrite. Did you realize, that `$term` is overwritten in every iteration? And why regular expressions? XML has xpath for that.

Answer (score 1):

**Abstract** your function.

Pass the **file** and the **search terms** as arguments to the function, and work with that.

Something like:

```
function parse_xml_file($file, $terms)
```

Then use pass `$file` and `$terms` when calling the function.

For more information, see **[Teh big bad manual](http://il.php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php)**.

Answer (score 0):

This revised function takes one parameter, the word to look for, and then uses it in the preg_match() function. So to use it all you need to do is call it with the term you're searching for. This should replace all of the hard coded functions.

```
function searchXML($search){

    // load SimpleXML
    $terms = new SimpleXMLElement('training_list.xml', null, true);
    echo <<<EOF
    <ul>
    EOF;
    foreach($terms as $term)
    {
        if(preg_match("/$search/i", $term->keyword)){
            echo <<<EOF
            <li>{$term->name}</li>
        EOF;
    }}
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: Wrong, you would override the `$term` argument with the `SimpleXMLElement`.

Comment: I just noticed my error and corrected it while formatting the code. I dunno if that was worth a vote down. You could have edited the answer and fixed it instead.

Comment: I could, but I don't like to edit other people's **code**. As it changes the meaning of the answer. I would change typos or grammar mistakes when I spot them, or fix indention in case your code needs it (but I won't change the code itself!). DV removed, happy browsing! :D

Comment: @KingCrunch: I meant the `$term` argument, him using the same variable in the foreach is a whole different issue.

Comment: @Truth Me too ;) Read the question above. There the OP did exactly this. Did say, that it makes anything better, but at least it's not (directly) JohnCondes mistake.

Comment: Thanks for your all your help and even for the snarky comments. It works great! Now I just need to fix all the other problems in this code... learning php from someone else's crappy code sure is fun.